# Java. if statement inside String as function argument

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Is there a way to include a simple if statement inside a Java String passed as argument to a function, like the following example

```
int TotalFiles = 3;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                     "Created " + TotalFiles + " file" + (if(TotalFiles>1){"s"}) + ".");
```

Comment: Hint: study java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase; they dont start uppercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [a ternary (or conditional) operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
"Created " + TotalFiles + " file" + (TotalFiles > 1 ? "s" : "") + "."
```

Side comment: non-constant variables in Java start in lower case, so `totalFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

try: `(totalFiles>0 ? "s" : "sometThingElse")`

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator.

```
JOptionPane
    .showMessageDialog(
        frame, 
        "Created " + TotalFiles + " file" + (TotalFiles > 0 ? "s": "") + "."
);
```

I also recommend:

- Naming your variable in `camelBack` as opposed to `CamelCase`
- Learning about `String` formats for easier to read/maintain formatting

Comment: I prefer to use brackets to make it clear this is not `TotalFiles > 0 ? "s": ("" + ".")`

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes makes sense. I actually misread your comment at first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Ternary operators.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Created " + TotalFiles + " file" + (TotalFiles > 0 ? "s" : "") + ".");
```

Ternary takes an expression such as `(TotalFiles > 0)`, compares it, and if it is true returns the value after the `?`, otherwise returns the value after `:`

This is equivilant to designing a private method that returns a string based on the expression:

```
private String isMultipleFiles( int totalFiles )
{
    if( totalFiles > 0 )
        return "s";
    else
        return "";
}
```